# Dojo i18n resource files with arguments

Tags: dojo, internationalization, resourcebundle

I am an advanced user of Dojo and now implementing i18n.
As part of it - I need the ability to have resource file with arguments - something like this:

```
root: {
  personalHello: 'Hello {1}'
}
```

So, when I call it with a name it will be something like this:

```
somDiv.innerHTML = i18n.personalHello['David']
```

Or something like this.
Can anyone refer me to an example that uses it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, found the answer in [this link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-dojo/).

Appearently, you can do something like this in resources:

```
root: {
  personalHello: 'Hello ${a1}'
}
```

And then call it like this from the code:

```
somDiv.innerHTML = dojo.string.substitute(i18n.personalHello, {a1: 'David'};
```

In Dojo >= 1.7 (AMD):

```
require(["dojo/string"], function(string) {
  somDiv.innerHTML = string.substitute(i18n.personalHello, {a1: 'David'};
})
```

Checked it. It works!

Comment: That link is a little out dated, I would recommend checking out [dojo 1.9 dojo/string](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.9/dojo/string) for the most up to date information.